# x axis in stat_qq not correct

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
df <- data.frame(y = rt(26, df = 5), name = letters)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(sample = y))
p + stat_qq() + stat_qq_line() + 
  geom_text(aes(
    label = letters, 
    y = qnorm(pnorm(sort(y))), 
    x = qnorm(seq(from = 1/27, to = 26/27, by = 1/27))))
```

Output:

[image]

The letters and the dots should be in exactly the same place. But they are not, especially towards the extremes, a and z.

Comment: The tails of random distributions often depart from the theoretical. You need to recalibrate your understanding of “random”.

Comment: As far as I get it the issue is that the x coordinates you set are different from the ones used by stat_qq to draw the points. Instead I would suggest to add labels via `stat_qq(geom = "text", label = letters)`.

Comment: @stefan, but I also needed the dots. In your solution, the dots go away, replaced by the letters. I need both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the smart advice from **@stefan** (many thanks for helping others), try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(y = rt(26, df = 5), name = letters)
#Plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(sample = y))
p + stat_qq() + stat_qq_line() + 
  stat_qq(geom = "text", label = letters,vjust=-0.5)
```

Output:

[image]